# How to mark text in gedit?

Tags: gedit

Can anyone guide me how to mark text in my source code in gedit as shown below ("TODO" word was marked with yellow color)?

[image]

I can't find a feature in the editor for me to apply this highlighting (so it persists) to other parts of text, beyond what is automatically highlighted. Is this possible?

I've [uploaded my source](http://www.mediafire.com/download/vi0t3fr53ievbpt/lab1b.c) (one small file) if you have gedit and want to view the highlighting to see what I'm trying to reproduce.

Comment: It's very difficult to determine what you're asking here - can you clarify precisely what you want to accomplish?

Comment: I want to mark the selected text in my source code. For example, "TODO" word was marked with yellow color above.

Comment: I think I understand now - I've made additional edits to your question - please double check to make sure I understood you correctly?

Comment: Looks like it may be part of the syntax highlighting theme you're using.

Comment: Does the editor also highlight other phrases in caps like `BUG:`? This is an interesting question because if there _is_ a way to manually apply that highlighting so it sticks, it would sure be nice to know how! The question is clear enough, just not sure if it's possible to manually apply that highlighting.

Comment: Folks, questions about tools commonly used by programmers _are on topic_. It's gedit, and he's editing code - I don't see a reason to close this.

Comment: Just checking, are you aware that `gedit` is a text editor, which stores *plain text*, with no "hidden" markup? That means, any highlighting is transient, generated at runtime, not persistent (unless you store some extra config information about a particular file somewhere). So you could clarify what exactly you mean by "apply this highlighting (so it persists)".

Comment: No, it doesn't highlight other caps phrases. I got this source from a C course from the internet and I think that the author made the word "TODO:" highlight in that way to mark for his student. But I don't know how he did.

Answer (score 1):

I think that searching text with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> will leave the text searched highlighted, otherwise you can look at the  [Smart Highlighting plugin for gedit](https://code.google.com/p/smart-highlighting-gedit/) .

If the highlight is not a consequence of a mark, it is clear that it rely on the synthax highlighter set for the current programming language ...

> gedit provides syntax highlighting for a wide range of markup,
>   programming, and scientific languages. If gedit recognizes the syntax
>   being used when you open a file, it will automatically highlight the
>   text. If your syntax or language is not highlighted upon startup, you
>   can select the appropriate syntax or language by clicking View ▸
>   Highlight Mode, and then choosing the desired syntax. Alternately, you
>   can select the syntax name from a list at the bottom of the gedit
>   window.

Comment: It just highlight but don't mark. What I want is like when you select a text and fill its foreground color in text processing (eg: MS Word, Libreoffice writer).

Comment: @dangnam2910 Oh, maybe I understood , look at the updated answer !

Comment: gedit is a text editor, not a word processor. You're not going to get the functionality of 'press a button and highlight the text'.